# Well-posedness of linear ODE problem on vector bundle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $\gamma \colon [0,\alpha] \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a smooth regular curve and let $N\gamma$ denote its normal bundle.

Recall that $N\gamma$ is a smooth vector bundle, whose fiber at $\gamma(t)$ is the orthogonal complement $\dot{\gamma}(t)^{\perp}$ in $T_{\gamma(t)}\mathbb{R}^{3} \cong \mathbb{R}^{3}$ of the tangent vector $\dot{\gamma}(t)$.

For any smooth section $V$ of $N\gamma$, we define $D_{t}V$ to be the orthogonal projection onto $N\gamma$ of the Euclidean acceleration $\overline{D}_{t}V \equiv \dot{V}$.

**Question**: Given a smooth function $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$, does the linear ODE system on $N\gamma$ 
$$
\begin{cases}
D_{t}V = f W\\
D_{t}W = -fV
\end{cases}
$$
have unique global solution for any initial condition $(v,w)$?

Comment: I would say yes. However, it would help if you provided more background. In particular, what did you try? What do you know about your vector bundle? What do you know about vector bundles in general?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I thought about looking at the system of ODEs in a smooth local trivialization of $N\gamma$. In fact, my vector bundle admits a smooth *global* trivialization. Is this the correct strategy?

Comment: Sounds like a good strategy, yeah. Take a global trivialization and consider the space of double sections, that is, the space of pairs $(v,w)$, where $v$ and $w$ are sections. In terms of a trivialization, this space looks like the space of functions from interval to $\mathbb{R}^4$, or equivalently, the space of paths in $\mathbb{R}^4$. This makes your ODE look like the flow of a time-dependent *linear* vector field. This flow exists for all time and for every initial condition (you don't need the assumption $v\cdot w=0$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval OK, thanks for the help! I have edited the question and removed the assumption on the initial condition.